# Why `sudo nginx -t` and `nginx -t` return opposite results for the very same file?

Tags: nginx

These commands return opposite results for `nginx.conf` - one is failed, another one is successful. Why?

```
$ nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> nginx: [emerg] open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
> ```

It sounds like the permissions for the `pid` file (as defined by the [`pid`](http://nginx.org/r/pid) directive) preclude your normal user from accessing it, thus the test of the configurations appears to fail.